# How to graph fractions of a second in AmCharts 4 with line chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have some data in the format of:

```
[
  {t: 0.2, val: 1},
  {t: 0.4, val: 5},
  {t: 0.6, val: 60},
  {t: 0.8, val: 3},
  {t: 1, val: 20},
  {t: 1.2, val: 55},
  ...etc
]
```

I've managed to make a line chart using a DateAxis for the X axis but I'm struggling to get it to understand the format I'm supplying the numbers in (fractions of a second), I can't find how to do it reading the docs about date formatters etc. AmCharts currently draws 4 data points for every point in the X axis.

This is the core of the code I have currently:

```
const chart = am4core.create('full-analysis-chart', am4charts.XYChart);

const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 100;

const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.data = data;
series.dataFields.dateX = 't';
series.dataFields.valueY = 'val';
```

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to just use a value axis for the X-axis? Your data isn't even in a valid date format.

Comment: @xorspark I was just having a brain fart, of course it should. Think I got a bit blind sided by every line chart example on the site showing a date axis and they talked about ordering dates with seconds occasionally etc. Thanks for snapping me out of it, big help.